# It's unconventional, but is "T's & C's" technically correct?

Tags: apostrophe

It looks a bit weird and isn't the commonly used term, but is it not correct? The apostrophe would be marking the shortening of "terms" to "t" and "conditions" to "c", of course.

Comment: In *speech*, I suspect if they were going to abbreviate at all, most people would probably lump both initials together and say **T and C's** (just as they'd ask for *"Two **G and T's**, please"* in a bar). But there's not really any meaning to the concept of "correct" here.

Comment: This from the [Acronym Finder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Terms-and-Conditions-(Ts%26Cs).html): 'What does _Ts&Cs_ stand for?
Ts&Cs stands for Terms and Conditions [
This definition appears very rarely and is found in the following Acronym Finder categories:

Slang/chat, popular culture
Business, finance, etc.]

Comment: @FumbleFingers The difference is that you wouldn't pluralize both words when you expanded that abbreviation. You'd ask for _two gin and tonics_, not _two gins and tonics_. (you're essentially treating it like a compound word _gin-and-tonic_) But the expanded version of _Ts and Cs_ is _terms and conditions_.

Comment: Darn it, I thought the question was on the form when I voted to close there, not the abbreviation.

Comment: Yep, "T's and C's" (with various punctuations) is a common term that would be understood by anyone in business in the US and most "average" people as well.

Answer (score 2):

> It looks a bit weird and isn't the commonly used term

It's certainly *a* commonly used term, and a search finds [plenty using each of the variants "Ts and Cs", "Ts & Cs", "T's and C's" and "T's & C's](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ts+and+cs%22).

Whether one uses apostrophes with single-letter capital abbreviations is something different style guides differ on. If you aren't writing to a style-guide then I'd note that to not use the apostrophe is generally the more modern style, and being consistent one way or the other is a very good idea.